# A set which is $\in$-transitive and well ordered by $\in$ is an ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

A set $x$ is said to be $\in$-transitive if $\forall y$ $\forall z$($ y \in x$ and  $ z \in y \Rightarrow z \in x$). A set $x$ is said to be an ordinal if $x$ and every member of $x$ is $\in$-transitive.

The following proposition is given:

Proposition: Every well ordered set is order isomorphic to a unique ordinal by a unique isomorphism.

Using this proposition how can I prove that  a set  which is $\in$-transitive and well ordered by $\in$ is an ordinal.

Comment: The definition of an ordinal as you give is not written correctly (from a grammatical point of view, and mathematical point of view).

Comment: I have altered the definition of ordinal to what I believe you intended. Please make appropriate alterations if your intention was different. Regardless, as @Asaf notes, the definition you originally posted was nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

The Proposition is not necessary (or particularly useful, as far as I can tell) to prove this result.

Suppose that $a$ is $\in$-transitive and well-ordered by $\in.$ In order to show that $a$ is an ordinal (that is, an $\in$-transitive set whose elements are $\in$-transitive), it remains only to show that the elements of $a$ are $\in$-transitive. By way of contradiction, suppose that not all elements of $a$ are $\in$-transitive, meaning that there is some non-$\in$-transitive $x\in a.$ Since $x$ is not $\in$-transitive, then there exist $y\in x$ and $z\in y$ such that $z\notin x.$ Since $a$ is $\in$-transitive, then $y\in x\in a$ implies that $y\in a,$ and since $z\in y,$ we likewise have $z\in a.$

So, at this point, we know that $x,y,z\in a$ with $z\in y,$ $y\in x,$ and $z\notin x.$ Do you see where the contradiction comes in? (What property of $a$ hasn't been used yet?)

Comment: Thanks for editing and the answer. So the subset $\{x,y,z\}$ of $a$ can not have the least element, which is a contradiction as $a$ is well ordered set. Am I right?

Comment: Well, to say that $\{x,y,z\}$ has no $\in$-least element, we'd have to demonstrate further that neither $x$ nor $y$ can be the $\in$-least element (all we've shown so far is that $z$ can't be the $\in$-least element, since $z\notin x$). However, since $\in$ well-orders $a,$ then $\in$ is a transitive relation on $a,$ so since $x,y,z\in a$ are such that $z\in y$ and $y\in x,$ we *must* have $z\in x$ by definition of a transitive relation. And there's the contradiction.

Comment: But from Axiom of Regularity we know that given sets $x$ and $y$, either $x \notin y$ or $y \notin x$. Does it not work?

Comment: @Cameron: If $x=\{x\}$ then $x$ is transitive and totally ordered by $\in$. Is it an ordinal? If yes, then $\{0\}$ is isomorphic to **two** ordinals. Inconceivable!

Comment: @Steve: Your approach (via Regularity) works just fine. The only advantage to the approach I outlined is that it works even if we don't take Regularity as a given, and in fact shows a stronger result: that if $a$ is a $\in$-transitive set on which $\in$ is a transitive relation, then $a$ is a $\in$-transitive set of $\in$-transitive sets.

Comment: @Asaf: Fixed! Thank you for drawing it to my attention.

Comment: Cameron: Mech butter.